# how to ship groovy scripts?

Tags: groovy, packaging

How should I package and ship my groovy scripts without assuming groovy to be installed (and on PATH) on client machine? However, JDK/JRE will be available on all client machines.

What I'm currently doing is to groovy-compile & bundle related scripts in a jar with groovy-all-xxx.jar included in the lib (Netbeans does this automatically). But the problem with this approach is - with every independent small script (project), I have to bundle the huge groovy-all jar creating a big binary.

Just wanted to know if there is any better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [extension mechanism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/index.html) for this - that way each client machine would have to download groovy-all-xxx.jar just once.